# Most volunteers provide me their images for acknowledgement. How should those without image be handled?

Tags: volunteers

I have a project and have several retired and current volunteers. I ask all volunteers to send me their images so I can put them in the acknowledgement page. However some don't reply me (who are also retired ones). How should I handle them?

- Use a generic image as the placeholder for those who I don't have image, because they should have a spot in the gallery?
- Just use the images I have, because simply naming all volunteers in the text is sufficient?

Comment: You don't mention the nature of the project or the context. To be on the safe side you should assume that the volunteers that don't reply don't want their picture to be posted, so you should use a generic image.

Comment: I understand that we should assume that they don't want to have their picture posted. But my question is: should I use a generic image, or should I not include that image at all? My project is about [community development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_development "Community development - Wikipedia"), but how does that different to other kinds of project?

Comment: _how does that different to other kinds of project?_ I suppose it depends on the type of project and the volunteers preferences in general. E.g. for a small to mid-size company with an _intranet_ project the assumption could be that it does not matter if they have an image up or not because everyone knows each other. _should I use a generic image, or should I not include that image at all?_ It may come down to personal preference and to site design. I'd go for no image at all but, again, it's personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if someone doesn't want their image to be shared, the way you should "handle them" is by being respectful of their wishes.

Do they even want to be *named*?

If they don't mind being named, list their names. If they don't want to be named, don't list them.

If they don't want their picture shared, don't share one :)

Comment: I understand that if they don't want so, I should respect that. The point is, how can I be sure that it's what they want when there is no response? I don't see any reason to assume that they don't want if they keep silence

Comment: @Ooker - easy: assume they don't want to be mentioned unless they say "yes". Don't assume permission to talk about someone - easy to get yourself in trouble that way :)

Comment: I guess this assumption is based on fear. Sometimes you need to fear to be safe, but in general I would like to not be fear. Is there a way to bother be respectful and not fearful?

Comment: @Ooker - there is no "fear" in assuming someone who doesn't respond doesn't want to be mentioned. It's basic courtesy and respect (or, it is in cultures of which I am aware). Word your page something like, "we want to thank our many volunteers, some of whom are below"